# Read text file, match & paste text in excel

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have text file test.txt which has 3 columns. The 1st & 2nd columns are separated by 2 spaces and the 2nd & 3rd columns by 6 spaces. Sample:

```
402115000518432  97517518878      IDLE
402115001509990  97517490827      IDLE
402115001555677  97517339229      IDLE
```

All the entries of 1st column begin with 40211

I want only the 1st column of text to be pasted in the 1st column of the excel file.

I was trying with the following code:

```
Dim pattern = "(?<=\s*40211.*).*"
Dim i = 1

For Each line In File.ReadLines(RichTextBox3.Text)
            Dim match = Regex.Match(line, pattern)

            If match.Success Then
                sheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = match.Value
                i += 1
            End If
        Next
```

But it is pasting all 3 columns and the 1st column does not have the 40211 part. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this expression instead:

```
40211[^\s]*
```

Comment: just wondering, what should i change in the pattern to get the entire row starting with 40211?

Comment: Would you mind answering this question for me please?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543061/excel-text-to-columns-using-vb-net?noredirect=1#comment49159090_30543061

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your pattern to this.

```
Dim pattern = "(^40211\d+)"
```

Comment: thanks. just wondering, what should i change in the pattern to get the entire row starting with 40211?

Comment: Would you mind answering this question for me please?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543061/excel-text-to-columns-using-vb-net?noredirect=1#comment49159090_30543061