# Excel Text-to-Columns using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have an excel sheet with variable number of entries in the column A. 
Sample:

```
402110000027547  97517161579      IDLE              402-11-150
402110000013260  97517117011      IDLE              402-11-190
402110000033664  97517125759      IDET              402-11-21
```

I want to execute text-to-columns and put these values in separate columns (A, B, C & D). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your input file is in CSV format?

Comment: No. I am using some other code to populate an excel worksheet. So its an excel workbook we're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working using this code:

```
With sheet
        .Columns(1).TextToColumns( _
        Destination:=.Cells(1, 1), _
        DataType:=Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        TAB:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, _
        Space:=True, _
        Other:=False, _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=False)
    End With
```

Thanks to this page
http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/06/28/excel-text-to-columns-from-vb-net/

Comment: Self help is the best help! Good Luck!